# Cargar select con dato que viene por json

Tags: php, json, laravel-blade

estoy trabajando con un modal y para cargar los datos lo estoy haciendo a con json, pero mi problema se gestiona en los siguiente, cuando quiero completar mi combobox NO SE COMO dejar marcado el dato que traigo seleccionado.  Mi código es el siguiente, en mi blade tengo lo siguiente

```
    $('.revisar').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                sit = $(this).attr('href');
                url="{{route('ver', ["id"=>"#REF#"])}}";
                url=url.replace("#REF#", $(this).attr('id'));
                $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('#modal').attr('action', sit);
                    $('#ed_md').modal('toggle');

                    if(!data.Estado){
                        alert("Error");
                    }else{
                        $('#nombre').val(data.nombre);
                        $('#email').val(data.email);
                        $('#area').html(data.area);
                    }
                });

            });

En mi Controlador, estos son los datos que traigo

public function datosGet($id){
        $commit=true;

        if(!is_numeric($id)){
            $commit=false;
            $id="";
            $nombre="";
            $email="";
            $area="";
        }

        if($commit){
            $seleccion = Postulante::where('id', '=', $id)->first();

            if($seleccion==""){
                $commit=false; 
                $id="";
                $nombre="";
                $email="";
                $area="";
            }else{
                $commit = true;
                $id=$seleccion->id;
                $nombre= $seleccion->nombre_completo;
                $email= $seleccion->email_postulante;
                $area=$seleccion->area_id;
            }
        }
    return response()->json(array("Estado"=>$commit, "id"=>$id, "nombre"=>$nombre, "email"=>$email, "area"=>$area), 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Y en mi modal tengo del blade tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for=""> Área</label>
                                    @php
                                        $ar= \App\Models\Area::where('vigencia', '=', 1)->orderBy('id')->get();
                                    @endphp
                                    <select name="area" id="area" class="form-control">
                                        @foreach($ar as $areas)
                                            <option value="{{$areas->id}}">{{$areas->abreviado}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

A través de este dato **`$('#area').html(data.area);`** paso a mi modal el combobox, lo cual me hace, pero no que no me trae es el area que tengo guardada en la base de datos y no se como realizar esto, quizas sea una bobada, pero no se me ocurre.  También intente poner en mi modal el combobox, pero llego a lo mismo porque no se como seleccionar el area que corresponde, por fa, ayuda

Comment: Después del value agrega `@if($aspirante->area == $areas->id) selected @endif`

Comment: Amigo y esta varible $aspirante de donde sale?

Comment: Tu vista no debería contener lógica tal como consultas a tu base de datos

Comment: BetaM no entendí! :'(

Comment: @Karli, es una suposición, porque no incluiste en la pregunta la variable que usas para el modelo.

Comment: Puse todo lo que tengo, traigo los datos por json y asi cargo mi modal

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega cómo obtienes el valor que debe quedar predeterminado en el `<select>`

Comment: Triby como he dicho es todo lo que tengo, se que en php puro comparo @if($aspirante->area == $areas->id) selected @endif, lo que no se es como traerlo desde el json, como tambien he dicho todo lo que he puesto es mi codigo, no se donde me falta ingresar algo mas: tengo un json que carga mis datos, uno que recibe y mi modal

Comment: ¿Estás obteniendo el `<select>` directamente de _Postulante_? El modelo solo debe manejar datos y no HTML.